# Button color changed due to background color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I changed background color of my activity using android:background. Background color changes but color of button background changes too. I want to keep button with default background and properties.

Button looks like as shown in this image.

[image: Button looks like this]

XML file of Activity is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#116493">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just set the background of your button. Issue solved

Comment: @Nimit, glad to hear .

Answer (score 1):

@Nimit Aggarwal: Please update your theme settings . Remove  `style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"` .
Add [button](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/your_image"
    android:text="Button" />
```

For demo purpose please follow [Android ImageButton selector example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/)

Comment: Update theme setting to what to get default button with background ? @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: Which theme to apply for default button?